# how to get json back from httplclient call?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console-application, httpclient

I am having some hard time get data as json from SharePoint rest api using HTTPClient. It returns data as xml. I am trying to set the headers to return json, but apparently I am not doing right.
Can someone help, please?

This is my code that I am testing right now:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization","NTLM");

                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                    HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://sp2016/_api/lists/getbytitle('Holidays')/items");
                    msg.Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    //var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://sp2016/_api/lists/getbytitle('Holidays')/items"));

                    //if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) { 
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Holidays>(content);
                }
```

Comment: You can convert your `XML` response to `Json` did you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You should generally include an `Accept` header alongside the request. Some servers with multiple output formats will use this to determine what content type to return.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```